# Is there a better way to find out of a file or directory exists?

Tags: dart, dart-io

This seems a bit cumbersome

```
var fileExists = 
    new File(path).existsSync() || 
    new Directory(path).existsSync() || 
    new Link(path).existsSync()
```

Is there a shorter or better way?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A shorter way is

```
import 'dart:io';

FileSystemEntity.typeSync(path) != FileSystemEntityType.notFound
```

See also https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/2883#issuecomment-108317456